# Why can't Microsoft store version of Office access redirected folders?

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-store

Our client has two computers that had preinstalled Office 365 from the MS store and I believe they are OEM licences for MSO '16 H&B.  The computers were not syncing with group policy because Netlogon was set to manual.  Once I fixed that and folder redirection occurred, no users can access their redirected folders from Office applications.  Explorer can access the folders just fine and so can other applications like notepad.

- I have uninstalled the desktop apps package from all users using the powershell command then installed Word from the store and the problem remains.
- I have tried adding the user's network profile directory to `trusted locations` but the issue remains.
- Installing Office 2016 H&B using exe works fine to access the files but I can't tell if it's the same license as there are multiple licenses on this MS account I'm looking at.

It is basically the same as this issue that was reported here but reinstalling did not fix the issue as stated above.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-2016-unable-to-access-redirected-folder/bafa00c8-e883-42d3-bdf3-7a6ace44a506

Comment: This is due to a limitation of UWP applications.  Office 2016 Home & Business and the Office installed through the Windows Store absolutely use different licenses.  This isn’t something trusted locations can solve.

Comment: As somewhat suggested in the thread you referenced there are one of two possible problems. You have the security permissions setup wrong for your roaming folders location (note - browsing by explorer successfully does NOT confirm it is configured correctly), or two - you have corruption in your offline file cache. First, disable offline files and see if it solves the issue. If not, confirm that the user has traverse folder and list folder permissions on every folder leading up to where the file is stored.

Comment: It does possibly look like a limitation in Windows store apps: https://superuser.com/questions/1357558/word-cannot-access-documents-or-desktop-freezes-on-exit

Comment: I heard back from their engineer that they are in talks to migrate to 365 licensing so this may all be moot in a month or two.  I second the possibility that store apps cannot access certain locations and Word does hang/crash on exit.  I will stay with my current solution of using non store Office until the talks are complete.  Office licensing is a mess right now for them.  I forgot to put that we did verify permissions were set correctly.  Thank your for the affirmations of my hunch.

Comment: It is definitely a limitation of Win store applications.
You can get the key for Win store purchased office apps however, so you can enter them in at office.com/setup and download the full installer.  That's what we ended up doing to resolve the issue.